# PostGIS: Is there any visualization window?

Tags: postgresql, visualization, postgis

I'm new user of PostGIS and PostgreSQL to ask, if there is window for visualization of data, similar to MS SQL or Oracle? If yes, where?

Comment: A database system has no "window", let alone a "visualization window".  Such UI is supplied by an application outside of the database. If you are referring to "Oracle" or "MS SQL" which client  tools exactly are you referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of such a tool. postgis is just an extension of postgresql; basically it manages data.

I would recommend you to use QGIS (it is a open source GIS visualisation software).

1. Download QGIS from https://www.qgis.org/
2. GO to the pluggin manager and install the Database connection manager
3. Go to Layer/Add postgis layer
4. Configure a connection to your existing postgis database
5. Choose the table you want to import.

(in fact any GIS visualization software should do the trick, but QGIS is free ;)

Comment: Thank You so much! I tried all the time to find visualization window, but simply there is no window. Im use to work with MS SQL or Oracle and their visual windows... Anyway thank You!

Comment: QGIS is excellent for this purpose. It basically is a visualisation window for PostGIS.